# Simple JDBC Query By Example (QBE) for Spring JDBC Template

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

This is a quick and dirty QBE method that covers about 60% of my use cases in my DAO. I just wanted to see if someone would take a quick look at it to see if there are any issues.

```
public List<Order> orderQuery(Order order) {

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("select * from orders ");

    List<String> clauses = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();

    if (order.getOrderID() != null) {
        clauses.add("order_id = ?" + order.getOrderID());
        values.add(order.getOrderID());
    }

    if (order.getAccountCode() != null) {
        clauses.add("acct_nmbr = ?");
        values.add(order.getAccountCode());
    }

    // TODO: Once I switch this to the AccountType enum, use order.getAccountType().getCode()
    if (order.getAccountType() != null) {
        clauses.add("acct_typ = ?");
        values.add(order.getAccountType());
    }

    if (order.getRsid() != null) {
        clauses.add("rsid = ?");
        values.add(order.getRsid());
    }

    if (order.getUserID() != null) {
        clauses.add("user_id = ?");
        values.add(order.getUserID());
    }

    if (order.getCurrentStatus() != null) {
        values.add(order.getCurrentStatus());
    }

    if (!clauses.isEmpty()) {
        sql.append("where ");
    }

    String whereClause = clauses.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));
    sql.append(whereClause);

    List<Order> result = jdbcTemplate.query(sql.toString(), orderRowMapper, values.toArray());
    return result;
}
```

Generally it's simple:
1. Put the SQL clause in a StringBuilder.
2. Check the various fields I care about and if they aren't null, add a clause for them.
3. Turn the list of SQL where clauses into a single string
4. Build the entire SQL statement.
5. Execute it with Spring JDBC Template.

Any external input?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of SQL injections.

Assuming that the `Order` object is sanitized, then the only suggestion I'd make is to make a class for your order query and extract the logic from your method into that class.

A quick example would be that:

```
public class OrderQuery {

    private List<String> clauses = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();

    public OrderQuery(Order order) {
        setOrderId(order.getOrderID());
        // ...
    }

    private void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        if (orderId != null) {
            clauses.add("order_id = ?");
            values.add(orderId);
        }
    }

    // ...

    public List<Object> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("select * from orders ");
        if (!clauses.isEmpty()) {
            sql.append("where ");
        }
        String whereClause = clauses.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));
        sql.append(whereClause);
        return sql.toString()
    }
}
```

And to call it from your now much less clustered method:

```
public List<Order> orderQuery(Order order) {
    OrderQuery orderQuery = new OrderQuery(order)
    List<Order> result = jdbcTemplate.query(orderQuery.toString(), orderRowMapper, orderQuery.getValues().toArray());
    return result;
}
```

But it could be further optimized by using something like builder pattern.

Comment: Doing my best to prevent sql injections, the parameterization should help. Thanks for looking at the code.